# WScript.Shell.run on multi thread

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know if there is a way to run a shell window on another thread than excel ?

The idea is to not freeze excel when I launch a shell.

for instance :

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
objShell.run "cmd /K CD C:\ & Dir"
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree and disagree with Praktik. I agree because you cannot create a real multi-threaded application in Excel. I disagree because you could use kind of trick to execute another script.
Let's assume you have a vbs script called "Script.vbs". Then you could code sth like this `taskId = Shell("wscript Script.vbs parms")`. The script would run independently from your VBA program. But may that's not what you want.

Comment: Hi. You mean launch a shell from a vba script ? We can already do that (for instance my original post). But when you launch  the command " objShell.run "cmd /K CD C:\ & Dir"" I think you have to wait the end to get back the control of excel.

Comment: Yes, launch a shell from a vba script but not by objShell.run. Because as you said you have to wait then. If you use Shell like I suggested you will get back control almost immeidately and you do not have to wait for the Script.vbs to finish.

Comment: Sorry, just tested your approach and it works as well. You will get back control almost immediately.

Comment: You mean you tried to launch a shell (which will launch an heavy script for instance) and you get immediate return on excel ?

Comment: Yes, for instance I did objShell.run "cmd /K CD C:\ & Dir" and I got immediate return to excel. I also closed excel and the display of all files continued.

Comment: Edit: objShell.run "cmd /K CD C:\ & Dir /s

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be NO, you cannot create multi-threaded application in Excel.

However you can use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to lock the current Excel Workbook.

Make sure you enable it back at the end of the code like so `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, that doesn't involve runing a script. The command only allow to not refresh the display in excel.